# (rviz:12054): Gdk-CRITICAL **: IA__gdk_drawable_get_depth: assertion `GDK_IS_DRAWABLE (drawable)' failed

Tags: rviz

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there,

after updating ubuntu maverick to natty, I get the following error running rviz

rosrun rviz rviz

(rviz:12054): Gdk-CRITICAL **: IA__gdk_drawable_get_size: assertion `GDK_IS_DRAWABLE  (drawable)' failed

(rviz:12054): Gdk-CRITICAL **: IA__gdk_drawable_get_depth: assertion `GDK_IS_DRAWABLE  (drawable)' failed

I am using KDE and assume my gtk-settings were wrong. Do I miss a package or something? I would appreciate any help! Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10574/(rviz:12054):-gdk-critical-**:-ia__gdk_drawable_get_depth:-assertion-%60gdk_is_drawable-(drawable)%27-failed/) by [Tobias](https://answers.ros.org/users/825/tobias/) on ROS Answers with karma: 156 on 2011-07-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I can answer that myself. I had to add

`export GTK_NATIVE_WINDOWS=1`

to my environment variables. Though the message still appears, rvis starts as usual.

Cheers, Tobias

---

Originally posted by [Tobias](https://answers.ros.org/users/825/tobias/) with karma: 156 on 2011-07-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1